In a finite commutative ring with unity, is intersection of principal ideals a principal ideal?
In a finite commutative ring with unity, is intersection of principal ideals a principal ideal?
It is clear that intersection of ideals will be an ideal but will it be a principal ideal?
I don't know how to approach this problem as I don't know about existence of LCM in a finite commutative ring with unity also I am unable to found out a counter example of this.

Which examples did you look at?

Praveen, I didn't work out an example, but if you need an idea to start, it feels like something like you could start with $\mathbb Z[a,b,c,d]$ and choose relations to try to get $(a)\cap (b)=(c,d)$ in the quotient. To make it finite, you could add additional relations that leave your important ones intact.
